# How to load the data from a external nested json file and print the values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

> [CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/441gF7eBvYtQYCi9mOMu?p=preview)
>
> Hi i'm facing problem to display the result from a json object to my view page. the screen shows empty but i'm getting the data in console. while using the ng repeat it shows some error " Duplicate Key in Repeater"
>
> The basic requirement for me is printing the title from json file and when i click on it it should show the Title="example"

```js
var myItemsApp = angular.module('myItemsApp', []);

myItemsApp.factory('itemsFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
  var itemsFactory = {
    itemDetails: function() {
      return $http({
          url: "action.json",
          method: "GET",
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        });
    }
  };
  return itemsFactory;

}]);


myItemsApp.controller('NavController', ['$scope', 'itemsFactory', function($scope, itemsFactory) {
  var promise = itemsFactory.itemDetails();

  promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.itemDetails = data;
    console.log(data);
  });
  $scope.select = function(item) {
    $scope.selected = item;
  }
  $scope.selected = {};
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myItemsApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>dynamic title</title>

  <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller=NavController>
    <h3>Load title dynamically</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <a class="list-group-item" ng-click="select(item)" ng-repeat="item in itemDetails">{{item.title}}</a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <h2>Title: {{selected.title}}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### action.json

```
{

   "product": [{
         "title": "Product View",
         "path": "test1"

      },

      {
         "title": "Product Add",
         "path": "2"

      },
      {
         "title": "Product Update",
         "path": "test3"


      },

      {
         "title": "Product delete",
         "path": "test4"

      }
   ],

   "page": [{
      "title": "About us"
   }]

}
```

Comment: use track by $index   try this code  <a class="list-group-item" ng-click="select(item)" ng-repeat="item in itemDetails  track by $index ">{{item.title}}</a>

Comment: @Dinesh : i tried track by index but i want my values to printed dynamically according to the changes in json ..so is there any solution i shared my plunker over here can you check?

Comment: i update your jsfiddle  is this you want http://plnkr.co/edit/RXbLsqb5phynyTuaxser?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have two nested `ng-repeat`

```
  <div  ng-repeat="(key,item) in itemDetails">
      <a ng-repeat="i in item">
        {{i.title}}
      </a>
   </div>
```

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/441gF7eBvYtQYCi9mOMu?p=preview)

Comment: see created demo.

Comment: thanks i have seen the demo (Y) but i have a doubt can u please help me is there any way to show "product" as a heading for CURD for product and Page as a heading for its contents.

Comment: see updated plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/441gF7eBvYtQYCi9mOMu?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

your json has products and page as keys. your promise gives you whole object you need to iterate and take product object and then you can access title.